# GitHub workflow workflow_dispatch missing in actions tab

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow, cicd

I created a workflow file and the workflow is not showing up in the GitHub actions tab

> 

```html
name: AZ Deploy Workflow
on:
  workflow_dispatch:  
    inputs:
      deploy-environment:
        description: 'Environment to deploy to'
        required: true
        default: 'dev'
      image-tag:
        description: 'Docker tag to deploy'
        required: true
        default: 'latest'
```

any ideas what's the issue.

Earlier I have added other workflow into the .github directory that shows in actions with no issue even if a put a empty file it does but not this one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your workflow is located in the **default branch**.

> To run a workflow manually, the workflow must be configured to run on the `workflow_dispatch` event. To trigger the `workflow_dispatch` event, your workflow must be in the *default* branch. For more information about configuring the `workflow_dispatch` event, see "[Events that trigger workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch)".

For more details, see the [Manually running a workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow) and [about the default branch](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-branches#about-the-default-branch).

**UPD**:

Testing it from a branch other than from the main branch can be done using the GitHub REST API:

```bash
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/workflows/WORKFLOW_ID/dispatches \
  -d '{"ref":"test-branch","inputs":{"deploy-environment":"dev","image-tag":"latest"}}'
```

You can replace `WORKFLOW_ID` with the workflow file name. For example, you could use `main.yaml`.

`ref` - your branch name.

For more details visit the official docs: [Create a workflow dispatch event](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event).

Comment: I am on the feature branch, I would need to test the workflow and new changes before merging to the main branch. is there is a way I could do it on feature branch?

Comment: @green just once merge this WF into the default branch and then you will be able to run it from the Actions tab even for other branches

Comment: I am not sure about the code, I need to test it

Comment: @green probably it would be enough to merge a part of the workflow with the inputs included. Then run it targeting your feature branch and test. After that, you can merge the rest of the workflow jobs and steps if everything is ok.

Comment: Testing it from a branch other than from the main branch can be done using the REST api from GitHub. Check the docs here: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event to create a POST to 
/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/workflows/{workflow_id}/dispatches

Comment: @RobBos thank you, extended my answer with this information.